# Can i create a window object with an existing frame

Tags: java

Can I create window object instead of frame? I mean when I am creating a window object with an existing frame and showing it nothing happens.

`Frame frame=new Frame();
 Window window=new Window(frame);
 window.show(); // nothing happens here`

Comment: Where is your code? The question is not clear.. Can you please make more effort and explain it a little bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to show the frame by calling `.setVisible(true)`, you can do this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title of the Frame");
frame.setVisible(true);
```

If you just want a window with stuff in it, you should use JFrame. The following example will create a window with two buttons in it.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SSCCE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title of the Frame");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Button 2");

        panel.add(b1);
        panel.add(b2);
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why I cant use window instead of frame? Is there any difference between them?

Comment: To be honest I don't know why. If you check here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ and click on JFrame you can see that it's an extension of Window, which basically means that it's a window with extra features added. From what I've learned pretty much everyone uses JFrame when creating windows. Google around some and you'll find plenty of examples! Good luck coding.